# HTML / Javascript Dynamic line using HR tag

Tags: javascript, html, line

I have create one flow diagram on user choice. On selecting option a line should be drawn.
Line is properly created but it is resetting the option that user selected.

```
var htmlLine = "<div style='padding:0px; margin:0px; height:" + thickness + "px; background-color:" + color + "; line-height:1px; position:absolute; left:" + cx + "px; top:" + cy + "px; width:" + length + "px;behavior:url(Scripts/-ms-transform.htc); -moz-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -o-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -ms-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg);'><hr></div>";
//
//alert(htmlLine);
document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;
```

last line is creating some problem. when last line is commented everything is fine.

Please help me...!!!

Comment: What is the some problem?

Comment: can you replace the double quotations with a single one?

Comment: The code posted seems incomplete. Can you make a jsFiddle and show what the user options are that are being reset? Is it the attributes of the line (thickness, rotation, etc.)?

The last line is only a problem because it is executing the var. The problem could be in the var, or in the code where the user is setting the options. If the options aren't there for the var to inject, the html will be other than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

one problem i see in your code is that you use single quotations on style.
You must have something like this : style=".....". You can escape the double quotations by using the '\' . Your code will look like this :
    `var htmlLine = "<div style=\"padding:0px;...etc`
-> the double quotation is escaped by the \ character